# div style.height and style.width not preserved

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, canvasjs

I have Canvas JS charts as divs with chart data in separate javascript file.
The charts are hidden by default. Only on clicking an OnClick event handler the charts need to be shown. I am using style.display='none' by default and OnClick I am setting style.display='block'. But it is not keeping the div style.height and style.width parameters fixed. The OnClick chart shown is small in size and I want it to be of the size printed in the div. How to achieve that ?

I use the code :

```
var x = document.getElementById(res);
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}
```

Clicking the on click event handler the charts supposed to be visible.

```
var str1= "chartContainer";
var res = str1.concat(dt);
var x = document.getElementById(res);
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}
```

The chart that is shown is small in size. Like :
https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501983526299

But it is supposed to preserve the div height and width , like :
https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501983527221

Comment: How are you setting the `width` and `height`? If you are setting them using Javascript, the values will be discarded when you set the `display` property to `none`, since that removes the element from the DOM, when you set it back to `display:block` it gets recreated anew. Did you try using `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`? Or setting the size using CSS, either of those should work.

Comment: Visibility:hidden does the trick. But the problem with visibility is , using visibility:hidden allocates the space for the <div>.  There are 20 hidden <divs> which are shown On click. Setting visibility:hidden allocates lots of space for all the divs. What is the way around ?

Comment: I am setting                                                                                                           var x = document.getElementById(res);                                                                        x.style.height ='370px';
x.style.width = '1000px';
x.style.display = "block";                                                                                         Still the size rendered is small. How to fix it ?                                                          Thanks

Comment: Could you post some code that reproduces the problem? The problem may be coming from somewhere else, or be browser specific. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raulsauco/7mL0c1a2/13/) where the elements get width and height assigned, then they are hidden using `display: none` and then made visible again. They preserve the properties.